# Developing an iOS app, questions about the API I should use. (thinking of SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

This is a pretty basic question and doesn't really need much depth for an answer. I was just currently interested in developing an app for iPhones and after learning the swift2 language from the Mac site, I was just wondering which API I should use.

I did some moderate research, and so far spriteKit seems like the way to go (bit of a hassle if I want to port it over to android, but not impossible). But I was just wanting to make sure it's the right way to go.

The app idea revolves around keeping track of some form of progress and being able to use this data to generate graphs for the user? I'd also like to add some image functionality to the application as well. (similar to the health app and how it measures distance walked?)

I know this sounds vague, but would spriteKit be able to do these things? Or is there another API worth having a look into? (I've checked out metal and sceneKit as well, but leaning towards the more 2D type apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view using spritekit for this is overkill.
There are some greats frameworks to do graphs like charts :
https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts
Spritekit is more gaming oriented, if you want a "simple" app you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `SpriteKit` is the right API to accomplish your problems.

`SpriteKit` is all about moving and manipulating images on the screen. I am quite familiar with the `SpriteKit` API.

I do not see any help for generating graphs or something like that.

Also it is not the right API to display a proper interface for "serious" apps.